# Background Image fade on some android devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I am stuck in very strange problem.
I am using a `background image` for my application. Up till now everything is smooth and normal but all of sudden My image appears fade in new devices for example moto G4+ and Moto G5+. But working normal on my coolpad and samsung 4x devices.
Below is normal image.

[image]

And below is image when it use it as background image.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sdl.apps.yaarri.views.fakeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fakeid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        ></RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is simplest of `xml` I am creating. 
One thing I want to mention that after implementing Account kit(Facebook)for login this thing appears to happen.
If I am using some simple image then it appears normal but with this image problem occurs. Please suggest me I am am doing some thing wrong or it is some memory issue.
On more thing I want to mention here is that when I close application and open it again,nothing changes fade issue remains. But when I clear app from recently opened applications list and then open my app then original image appears as background.

Comment: Have you tried to add same image with different dimensions in drawables, Like drawables-ldpi, drawables-hdpi?

Comment: which theme are you using @ Vyas ?

Comment: @RakeshPolo yes I put image in drawable ,in xdpi and xxdpi. But doesnt matter in any case same thing happens.

Comment: A.N.T  
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: try changing the image file name.. clean your project, rebuild etc

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue.
The problem was with Facebook theme.

My code to set account kit

```
uiManager = new SkinManager(
            SkinManager.Skin.TRANSLUCENT,
    getResources().getColor(R.color.apptheme_color),
    R.drawable.background,
            SkinManager.Tint.WHITE,
        0.01)
```

and in manifest it was like:-

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    tools:replace="android:theme" />
```

So this was replacing app theme and setting its own image as background and with fade(transulent) effect.
What I did? Just remove the backkground image part in UImanager.

```
uiManager = new SkinManager(
            SkinManager.Skin.CONTEMPORARY,
    getResources().getColor(R.color.apptheme_color));
```

This will show white facebook login page but wont effect app theme.

Hope ,no body will face this...Namaste

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem before with appearance of background images in some devices. 
Then, I find that it depends to the screen mode of the device. See here how change screen mode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UoxvkwsiJ8 
and check if this is the cause of your issue or not.